# Image in swift, how?

Tags: swift

Good afternoon, I'm learning swift and I want to place an image but I still don't know how to do ,it with label it was easy.

```
class NotificationView: MessageView {
private let detalleSolicitudes = UILabel(text: "¡Hola! tienes mas de una solicitud", font: .poppins(size: 12), textColor: .greenSanna(), textAlignment: .center, numberOfLines: 1)
//MARK:- "search" is the image I have in my Assets
private let imagenSolicitud: String = "search"
private let solicitud = UILabel(text: "Title test", font: .poppins(size: 12), textColor: .greenSanna(), textAlignment: .center, numberOfLines: 1)
private let fechaHoraSolicitud = UILabel(text: "Title test2", font: .poppins(size: 12), textColor: .greenSanna(), textAlignment: .center, numberOfLines: 1)

    private let button = UIButton(title: "Ir al estado de la Solicitud", titleColor: .red)

    override init() {
        super.init()
        //this does not allow me
        addView(view: imagenSolicitud)

        addView(view: detalleSolicitudes)
        addView(view: solicitud)
        addView(view: fechaHoraSolicitud)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func Solicitud(_ text: String) {
        self.solicitud.text = text
    }
    func FechaHoraSolicitud(_ text: String) {
    self.fechaHoraSolicitud.text = text
    }


    @objc func handleButton() {     
        closeMessageView()
    }
```

}

Comment: You're just trying to add a `String`. You probably want a `UIImageView`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview

Comment: replace it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private let myNewImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imagenSolicitud))
```

This will create you UIImageView. But maybe still need to add frames or constraints to see the result. Depending on the context.

Comment: thanks, How do I make the image smaller?

Comment: ContentMode property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode to control stretch.
To reduce the size, reduce the height and width of the frame. For example: myNewImageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 15, height: 15)

Comment: How could I place two labels continuously horizontally?